# .show() not working in PtQt4

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, show, atom-editor, qwidget

When I run the code below, I should be able to see a new window that I created. However, when I run it, I can see the new window appearing for a split second and disappearing. What could be the problem?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
applicationDefinition = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
windowFigure = QtGui.QWidget()
windowFigure.show()
```

Comment: `applicationDefinition.exec_()`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

applicationDefinition = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
windowFigure = QtGui.QWidget()
windowFigure.show()
applicationDefinition.exec_()
```